# Java. Save file as root in Linux

Tags: java, root

How I can save file generated by java application in folder with root access?

Comment: Can I invoke popup with root password request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The straight forward way to do that is to run your application as the root user.

Another solution is to ask to the user the root password. To do that, you have to ask the "su" command of your system. Be careful, your user must have the "wheel" group. Or, you can use sudo (make sure that sudo is installed and configured for the current user).

As caarlos0 said in the comments, you can use "kdesu" or "gtksu/gksudo" if you prefer.

Of course, your application is not portable ! On windows, there's no "su", "sudo", etc.